# Remove Base URL from a link in a string

Tags: php

I have a string with an image link.

```
$image_link_raw = 'http://website.com/files/2012/10/image001.png';
```

Now I wanted to remove `http://website.com` and just get `/files/2012/10/image001.png` like:

```
$image_link_raw = '/files/2012/10/image001.png';
```

Is there a way to do that in PHP?

Comment: yes, several ways, what have you tried?

Comment: Splitting by `array(".com", ".net", ".info", ".edu", ".gov", ... );` is one way.

Comment: @Nile: I'm quite fond of `website.co.uk`, `website.me` & `website.ws`. Should I include those and the [hundred+ others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) in my array as well? ;-)

Comment: not forgetting: http://64.34.119.12/questions/12787863/remove-base-url-from-a-link-in-a-string et al

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i guess we are just giving answers then ?

```
<?php
$image_link_raw = 'http://website.com/files/2012/10/image001.png';
$p=parse_url($image_link_raw);
//print_r($p);
echo $p['path'];
```

Answer (score 18):

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

[`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) works great (and can get you other details like host, port, protocol, and more.)

---

```
<?php

  $url = 'http://website.com/files/2012/10/image001.png';

  echo 'URL Parts:' . PHP_EOL;
  var_dump(parse_url($url));

  echo PHP_EOL . 'And specific to path:' . PHP_EOL;
  echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

[Resulting output](http://ideone.com/LM8sl):

```
URL Parts:
array(3) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(11) "website.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(27) "/files/2012/10/image001.png"
}

And specific to path:
/files/2012/10/image001.png
```

Answer (score 6):

I would look at the [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function in php, it will be the `['path']` value.