# How to get the hostname without TLD from a url

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm in the process of creating a website.  Every time the user uploads a link, I need to save the link and its name/value.  This is hard to explain.

Here's what I'm trying to say.  Lets say the user pastes a link in an input.  `https://www.google.com/`  The link needs to be saved in an XML file.  When I call the link:

```
<a href="<?php whatever the php is ?>"> </a>
```

I want to also call the name:

```
<a href="<?php whatever the php is ?>">Google</a>
```

I want to extract "google" from "https://www.google.com/"

I know I could use:

```
str_replace(' ', '', )
```

But not all links are the same.
I know this code won't work because I already tried it. 
I know the right code is simple probably 3 lines.  So I would really appreciate it if you guys could help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get domain name from full URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027102/get-domain-name-from-full-url)

Comment: This thread may help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787863/remove-base-url-from-a-link-in-a-string

Comment: No dats not what i want. i know how to tho what the persons want in the other article.. this is a little diffrent.. not every links are from the same websites

Comment: This is a very difficult task to achieve, given the various ways domains can be structured, E.G http://domain.com, http://subdomain.domain.com, http://domain.co.uk, http://subdomain.domain.co.uk etc. You will need to create a function that strips out every known tld, and remove any subdomain (including www)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parse the url. get the host part and explode the string with a dot (.) as delimiter.

```
$url="https://google.com/";
$parts = parse_url($url);
$parts=explode('.',$parts['host']);
echo $parts[0]; // parts[1] contains com, parts[0] contains google
```

To work with urls that contain 'www' you might do something like this. Mind that this is not working with subdomains.

```
echo getName("http://www.google.com"); //prints google

function getName($url){

    $parts = parse_url($url);
    $parts=explode('.',$parts['host']);
    $data=$parts[0]=="www"?$parts[1]:$parts[0];
    return $data;
}
```

To work with every url, including subdomains I think it is more easy to use a regex. I adapted the function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027102/get-domain-name-from-full-url) question to fulfil your needs.

```
function getName($url){

  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
    return explode('.',$regs['domain'])[0];
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: $parts will be array (
  0 => 'www'
  1 => 'google'
  2 => 'com'
)

and not all urls might have www

Comment: edited the function so it will work for url with and without www. subdomains will not work.